# php random times table between two numbers

Tags: php

need to create a php random multiplication table between two numbers.

two numbers generated should be between 1 and 12

every time a person views the code via the website its on the two numbers should be different.

this is my code and at the moment it generates a number like this: 15441653899327

my intended ouput should look like this: Random times table example: 12 * 4 = 48(random 2 numbers to multiply every time)

what am i doing wrong?

```
    ?php 
    $rand = rand(1,12);
    $a = rand(1, 12);
    $b = rand(1, 12);
    $sum = $a*$b;

    echo $rand . "<br>";
    echo $a . "<br>";
    echo $b . "<br>";
    echo $sum . "<br>"

?>
```

Comment: Don't use `echo` everywhere. You only use that to output.... or add new lines, not clear what the intended output is.

Comment: my intended output should look like this:  Random times table example: 12 * 4 = 48 //number should change everytime page is visited

Comment: So you want `$a`, `$b`, and then the product of those numbers outputted? How is `echo rand();` used?

Comment: the numbers should be random everytime the page is refreshed on the server

Comment: Yes, `rand`, as `rand(1, 12)` will pick a number between 1 and 12. Is that what you want? Per manual, `If called without the optional min, max arguments rand() returns a pseudo-random integer between 0 and getrandmax(). If you want a random number between 5 and 15 (inclusive), for example, use rand(5, 15).`

Comment: my problem is i dont see anything being multuplied just seeing random numbers. my output should look like this: Random times table example: 12 * 4 = 48 and im getting this: 2
10
2
20

Comment: Strangely enough those `echo`s with the assignment display nothing. *But* they do perform the assignments. @MetroProdigy the random number you see is the 1st `echo` where you display the value of a `rand()` *without* var assignment.

Comment: changed my code this is what that displays now: 8
1
6
6 just random numbers?

Comment: @MetroProdigy: It might be time for that coffee break. Don't you see a pattern for the last 3 numbers. Ergo 1 * 6 = 6

Comment: LOL now i do wow, so whats the first number for?

Comment: Its your `echo rand()` which has no bounds other than max int

Comment: how would i make it display as is when i visit it via server: (Random times table example: 12 * 4 = 48) that exact way

Comment: Look up `concatenation` with `php echo`. FrankerZ's answer addresses some hints in this direction.